# How to register localhost website in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, sap-commerce-cloud

I am using Hybris framework for setting up an e-commerce site in local machine. How can I register a local site in google analytics?

Comment: A details instruction given here .. https://help.sap.com/viewer/a74589c3a81a4a95bf51d87258c0ab15/1811/en-US/8bc829d086691014a40783e96b9091ac.html

Answer (score 12):

2019 onwards, we do not need to do any extra configuration to test Google Analytics in a `localhost` environment. Just try creating separate properties for your local dev environment with any random domain, even http://example.com works.

Then, get the respective tracking code and put it in your local site and Google Analytics should start to track upon receiving pageviews/events.

Comment: This answer is correct. Google Analytics will collect data even though you're testing on localhost. The reason why Google Analytics ask for your domain is so that it can resolve links in your reports (e.g. All Pages report).